# Android + Chrome 90 = Apps Hanging

Tags: android, google-chrome, cordova

We have a Cordova app that has been running just fine for thousands of users.  We had reports starting last night (2021-04-14 10PM Central) that a handful of users have their app hanging on startup.  I know about a month ago we had app issues when Google released some updates for Chrome and WebView that [caused a problem with many apps](https://www.theverge.com/2021/3/22/22345696/google-android-apps-crashing-fix-system-webview).

I personally can't recreate this issue that a handful of people are reporting.  However, I also can't update to Chrome 90 in Google Play (which was released very recently).  Is anyone aware of issues with Chrome 90 on Android, causing other apps to hang (especially apps that depend on a webview)?  I'm not sure where to find these reports.  I'm also not sure why I can't update to Chrome 90 on any of my Android devices.

**UPDATE:**

I couldn't update Chrome to v90 on my Android devices, but I COULD update the Android System Webview app, which also had updates on April 13.  My app hangs with this update.  I will need to research why, but is there anyone that knows of other cordova apps that don't work well with this Android System Webview update?  Are there known bugs yet?

Comment: I've updated the Android System Webview on a device to 90.0.4430.66 and tested a couple of Cordova apps and they don't seem to hang. Could it be a specific plugin in your app that's causing the hang? Are you able to get any error details using Chrome Dev Tools or Android Studio Logcat?

Comment: Thanks Dave, that's helpful to know it's not all Cordova apps.  Debugging is my next step this AM now that I recreated it.  If I find a smoking gun I'll post an update here.

Comment: Looks like CSP processing may have changed in the latest Chrome 90?  I am getting a lot of CSP errors about `file://localhost/` assets being refused.  This includes all the core cordova assets for the app.  Adding this to the CSP seemed to let it through.  So maybe this was a hole in my CSP that Chrome 90 closed?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a result of Content Security Policy (CSP) differences in the Chrome 90 release.  We use the Ionic webview plugin and it serves the main assets on a `file://localhost` scheme/host setup for Android.  We didn't have this in our Content Security Policy, which worked just fine up until Chrome 90.  After Chrome 90 it got blocked, so we had to add `file://localhost` to the `default-src` and the `style-src` areas of our CSP.

Hopefully this can help others who get bit by this.